# How do you increase the resolution of a contour plot in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, contour

I am using an analytical 2D function to make a contour plot. However, I do not get a smooth contour. (For example it should have been a circle but I get a oval shape.)
Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
splot f(x,y) t ''
set dgrid3d; set view 0,0
set cntrparam levels 10
set contour base
set nosurface
unset ztics 
unset zlabel
set border 15
replot
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stackoverflow! We love to help! But please, simplify your questions, by formatting them nicely. [Here is a How-To](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a matter of scale of the axes.
You can change the ranges of the axes using the xrange/yrange, etc
See, for example http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node294.html

Comment: I had tried changing the xrange/yrange option earlier, but it didn't work. 
I have now switched to Python for making the contours, I'm getting a satisfactory result there.